# Applet flickers with no image present

Tags: java, applet, screen

Im currently building an applet and ran into an updating/repainting problem. I have string drawn that updates the coordinates of the mouse. The problem starts when I move the mouse. The coordinates update (by means of `repaint()` within the `mouseMoved()` method, but the applet flickers until I stop moving.

I've tried looking for solutions, but they only deal with if there was an image present. My applet only contains buttons, text (`drawString()`) and a gradient background. When it flickers, everything but the buttons flickers. Is there an alternative to stop the flickering when dealing with an applet that DOESNT use image files?

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov I just checked and it's returning false.

Comment: Try to use it in `init()`, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov That helped a lot using the invokeAndWait. All I have left is just a slight occasional flicker

Comment: It solved the problem of it flashing like a nightclub. Now its just tit for tat that I can work out. I'll accept the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java Swing there is a concept of [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) (EDT):

You can try putting in your `Applet.init()` method

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        createAndShowGUI();
    }
});
```

and to perform all related GUI stuff only in EDT.